# maven-assembly-plugin step failure: "[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter"

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to add a global version property to my multi-module 
Maven project, so that I can easily update the version of all 
modules by updating a single property rather than several pom 
files. The problems is that this property is breaking maven-
assembly-plugin that collects the compile module jars into a zip 
folder for distribution. When the version was hard-coded in all 
the pom files, everything worked swimmingly. When I converted to 
a property, however, the individual module jars still compiled, 
but the maven-assembly-plugin step failed after the following 
warning: "[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered 
in this artifact inclusion filter"

The assembly filters seem to be missing the modules, I just can't 
explain why this happens when I use the global property, or how 
to fix it.

Project structure:

```
    MyProject
        --ModuleA
          pom.xml
        --ModuleB
          pom.xml
        --Distribution
          src\main\assembly\distribution-assembly.xml
          pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

MyProject/pom.xml:

```
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${global.version}</version>

    <properties>
        <global.version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</global.version>
    </properties>
```

ModuleA/pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <version>${global.version}</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
```

ModuleB/pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <version>${global.version}</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ModuleB</artifactId>
```

Distribution/pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <version>${global.version}</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <artifactId>Distribution</artifactId>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>
              src/main/assembly/distribution-assembly.xml
            </descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>
                single
              </goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Distribution/src/main/assembly/distribution-assembly.xml:

```
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <moduleSets>
      <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <includes>
          <include>com.mycompany:ModuleA</include>
          <include>com.mycompany:ModuleB</include>
        </includes>
        <binaries>
          <outputDirectory>MyBuildFolder</outputDirectory>
          <outputFileNameMapping>mycompany${module.artifactId}.${module.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
          <unpack>false</unpack>
         </binaries>
       </moduleSet>
     <moduleSets>
```

Warning:

```
    [WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact 
    inclusion filter:
    o  'com.mycompany:ModuleA'
    o  'com.mycompany:ModuleB'
```

Error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly- 
    plugin:2.4:single (make-assembly) on project Distribution: 
    Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bin: You must 
    set at least one file. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: What command do you execute? And how do you declare the assembly plugin in the pom?

Comment: I have tried "mvn clean install" and "mvn clean deploy" and both fail. I have updated the Distribution/pom.xml up above to show how I declare the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your ModuleA and ModuleB as a depenedency of the distribution pom.

the Dstibution/pom.xml should look like this :

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <version>${global.version}</version>
</parent>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<artifactId>Distribution</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
        <version>${global.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>ModuleB</artifactId>
        <version>${global.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>
            src/main/assembly/distribution-assembly.xml
          </descriptor>
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
          <goal>
            single
          </goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```